# Fractional Chi-Squared Distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function, chi-squared

Is there a version of the Chi-Squared distribution where non-whole-number inputs are allowed?  I'm curious about the transition from the PDF being convex (the yellow and green lines below) to it being concave (the rest of the lines below) between the inputs $2$ and $3$.

[image]

I was wondering for what input between these values the PDF would be a straight line.  My guess is $e$, due to its ubiquitous appearances in mathematics.

If there are no fractional continuations of this distribution, are there any other ways to find out what that constant between $2$ and $3$ which produces a line would be?

Comment: I am not sure that "concave" or "straight line" apply here, but I suspect that $k=2$ is the critical value you are looking for.  Try to find the density at $x=0$, i.e. $\lim\limits_{x \to 0^+} \frac{1}{2^{k/2}\Gamma(k/2)}\; x^{k/2-1} e^{-x/2}\;$ for $k$ above, below and equal to $2$

Comment: @Henry I added picture to clarify and to show that $k = 2$ is still convex.

Comment: @Henry Okay, I see what you mean now after playing with it in Desmos.  At $k = 2$, it has a globally convex shape, and as you nudge away from $k = 2$, it starts to look either concave or convex near the $y$-axis, which extends right as you continue and either reinforces or overtakes the original convexity.

Comment: The chi-squared pdf given in the wiki article you got the picture from is valid for noninteger k.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An obvious answer is the  [Gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Related_distributions) family $\Gamma(\alpha,\beta)$, where the two parameters are positive real numbers.  (See [also](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-square_distribution#Gamma,_exponential,_and_related_distributions).) The density function for a $\Gamma(\alpha,\beta)$ random variable is
$$f(x)=\frac{\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-\beta x}.$$
(Here $\Gamma(\alpha)$ is what it takes to make $\int_0^\infty f=1$, namely, the
[Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).)
The chi-squared distribution with $k$ degrees of freedom is a $\Gamma(\frac k 2,\frac 1 2)$ random variable, so one can understand a "chi-squared rv with $1/3$ degrees of freedom" to be a $\Gamma(1/6,1/2)$ random variable, and so on.

Comment: +1 - and as $\alpha=1$ is the value which changes the density of the Gamma distribution at $x=0$ from being infinite to be being $0$ (it is positive but finite when $\alpha=1$ as you then have an exponential distribution), this corresponds to $2$ degrees of freedom for the chi-squared distribution